# Linear replacement

Tags: probability-distributions

Is it true that for any discrete random variable ξ the equality holds: $F_{aξ + b} (x) = F_{ξ}(\frac{x− b}{a})$ $∀x, a, b ∈ R (a \ne 0).$

Comment: what do you think? What have you tried?

Comment: If $F$ is the CDF, then just go to the definition and you can easily prove this.

Comment: True not only for discrete but also for continuous random variables.